# avoid java.util.ConcurrentModificationException using ArrayList and recursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm trying to construct binary tree from given edges and root. I iterate over all lines and set left child to given node(and right child if second occurrence of given node is found). And when child node is set I remove this element from ArrayList and call function recursively on child.

```
List<Integer[]> edges = new ArrayList<>();
```

This array list is e.g:

```
3 4
3 0
4 5
1 3
2 4
```

and root is `1`.
I have class Node

```
public class Node {
public Node left;
public Node right;
public int key;

public Node(int k) {
    key = k;
    left = null;
    right = null;
}
...}
```

And my function to construct a tree is:

```
public static void edgeToNodes(Node root) {
    if (root == null) return;
    int count = 0;

    for (Iterator<Integer[]> iterator = edges.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Integer[] edge = iterator.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < edge.length; i++) {
            if (edge[i] == root.key) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    Node left;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        left = new Node(edge[1]);
                        root.setLeft(left);
                    } else {
                        left = new Node(edge[0]);
                        root.setLeft(left);
                    }

                    iterator.remove();
                    count++;
                    edgeToNodes(left);
                } else {
                    Node right;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        right = new Node(edge[1]);
                        root.setRight(right);
                    } else {
                        right = new Node(edge[0]);
                        root.setRight(right);
                    }

                    iterator.remove();
                    edgeToNodes(right);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that it gives me `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` on line `Integer[] edge = iterator.next();` and `edgeToNodes(left);` How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: I'm having a hard time envisioning what the resulting tree is supposed to look like.  What do you expect your output to be?

Comment: @IanMcLaird Then I traverse tree inorder and in this example I expect: 5 4 2 3 0 1

Comment: Is part of the goal here to remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing elements from the list while iterating on it.

It would work if you did it with via only **one** iterator. The problem is that you use recursion and therefore create several iterators which modify the same list. This causes the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You could build the nodes in a more iterative way.

- Start from the root node.
- Maintain a list of nodes to visit (lets call it `pendingNodes`).
- Initialize it with the root node.
- While the list of pending nodes is not empty :

  - Take the first element of `pendingNodes`.
  - Find its potential children.
  - If there are some children nodes that are not already visited

    - Link them to the parent node.
    - Add them to the list of `pendingNodes`.

Here is an example of code :

```
public class Problem {

  private List<Integer[]> edges;
  private LinkedList<Node> pendingNodes = new LinkedList<>();
  private Map<Integer, Node> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();
  private Set<Integer> visitedNodes = new HashSet<>();

  public Problem(List<Integer[]> edges) {
    this.edges = edges;
  }

  public void run(Integer root) {
    //Initialization
    Node rootNode = new Node(root);
    this.pendingNodes.add(rootNode);
    this.nodeMap.put(root, rootNode);

    while(!pendingNodes.isEmpty()) {
      Node parent = pendingNodes.poll();
      for (Integer[] edge : edges) {
        if(edge[0].equals(parent.getKey())) {
          link(parent, edge[1]);
        } else if (edge[1].equals(parent.getKey())) {
          link(parent, edge[0]);
        }
      }
      visitedNodes.add(parent.getKey());
    }
  }

  public void link(Node parent, Integer child) {
    if(!visitedNodes.contains(child)) {
      //get the corresponding node, create it if not exists
      Node childNode = nodeMap.get(child);
      if (childNode == null) {
        childNode = new Node(child);
        nodeMap.put(child, childNode);
        pendingNodes.add(childNode);
      }

      //Choose between left and right...
      if (parent.getLeft() == null) {
        parent.setLeft(childNode);
      } else {
        parent.setRight(childNode);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Build the input dataset
    List<Integer[]> edges = Arrays.asList(
        new Integer[]{3, 4},
        new Integer[]{3, 0},
        new Integer[]{4, 5},
        new Integer[]{1, 3},
        new Integer[]{2, 4}
    );

    Problem problem = new Problem(edges);
    problem.run(1);

    Map<Integer, Node> nodeMap = problem.nodeMap;
    for (Node node : nodeMap.values()) {
      System.out.println(node);
    }
  }

}
```

Output (I customized `Node#toString()`):

```
0 => {null, null}
1 => {3, null}
2 => {null, null}
3 => {4, 0}
4 => {5, 2}
5 => {null, null}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand what happens here: node.setLeft(node);

Comment: in my task edge[0] or edge[1] can be parent

Comment: @user2950602 So how do you choose which one is the parent?

Comment: I tried to go through list, find root, choose another element on that edge as child, recursively do the same with child

Comment: @user2950602 Then it is like walking through a graph. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that each time you do a recursion, you create a new iterator over the same list. That iterator (at some point) then removes items from that list and you go back up in your recursion. However back up one step your list just lost an element WHILE you were iterating over it without it being removed by the iterator itself (it was removed by the iterator one step further down the recursion line).

=> ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: What solution is proposed?